# Bulk Insert partially quoted CSV file to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to load a CSV file to MS SQL Server table using below command

```sql
bulk insert emp1
from 'testfile/emp.csv'
with (data_source = 'src_gl_details'
 ,format = 'CSV'
 ,FIRSTROW = 2
,FIELDQUOTE = '"'
,ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n'
)
```

With is command I am getting error

> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 13
> Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".`

When I removed `format = 'CSV'` from the command then it works but no record inserted to the table.

Need help on this.

Below is my sample file

id,name

1,"\"John\""

2,"\"Mike\""

Comment: Also, the path is clearly incomplete; I assume that is simple to mask the actual value?

Comment: It was formatting issue, updated file format in post. Can you please check now

Comment: Why do your values have escaped double quotes around them? Seems you should really be fixing what ever is extracting the data, to be honest.

Comment: escape character is used because name itself is contains double qoutes.

Comment: So the clients' names aren't `John` and `Mike` they are `"John"` and `"Mike"`? I've, personally, never met anyone who has double quotes in their names, let alone their entire name wrapped in them.